# Log4j2 programmatic message substitution (Replacement for PatternLayout from log4j)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

We are migrating our logging away from log4j to log4j2. However I have issues with migrating a class that extends `PatternLayout` as that is now `final`.

The old pattern layout code replaces all occurrences of `\r` and `\n` with `|` **except** if it's a stacktrace.

I looked through the documentation of log4j2 but haven't found a good fit for that kind of problem yet. So far I don't believe this to be possible with XML configuration, but just with java code.

Any ideas on how we can replace certain characters in a log string **if** a condition is met?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regexp to replace those characters.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

`%replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{}`

This seems to be a duplicated question: [How to remove or replace newline from log messages log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466025/how-to-remove-or-replace-newline-from-log-messages-log4j)

In the other hand, `PatternLayout` extends `AbstractStringLayout`, so you could make a "*custom PatternLayout*".

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/PatternLayout.java

Comment: Does this keep stacktraces separated by newlines?

Answer (score 0):

You could try an approach like [the one I suggested as an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036831/3284624) regarding routing exception logs to a separate appender. You could have an appender that rejects messages with exceptions (via setting the `ExceptionFilter` property onMatch="DENY") and at the same time uses the replacement pattern similar to the one suggested by devwebcl

`%replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{|}`

Then have a second appender which will handle messages with exceptions. This appender would not use the replacement pattern.

So here is a java file to generate some logs:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();   

    public static void main(String[] args){

        if(log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug("This is some debug!\r\nThis is the second line of debug.");
        log.info("Here's some info!\r\nMore info on another line.");
        log.error("Some error happened!");

        try{
            specialLogic();
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            log.error("Woops, an exception was detected.", e);
        }
    }

    public static void specialLogic(){
        throw new RuntimeException("Hey an exception happened! Oh no!");
    }
}
```

Here is the log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">

    <Appenders>

        <File name="ExceptionFile" fileName="logs/app.log" immediateFlush="true"
            append="true">
            <ThrowableFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <File name="logFile" fileName="logs/app.log" immediateFlush="true"
            append="true">
            <ThrowableFilter onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %replace{%msg}{[\r\n]+}{|}%n" />
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="logFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ExceptionFile" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is some sample output:

```
2019-11-15 19:39:25.453 [main] DEBUG example.SomeClass - This is some debug!|This is the second line of debug.
2019-11-15 19:39:25.456 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass - Here's some info!|More info on another line.
2019-11-15 19:39:25.456 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - Some error happened!
2019-11-15 19:39:25.456 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - Woops, an exception was detected.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Hey an exception happened! Oh no!
    at example.SomeClass.specialLogic(SomeClass.java:25) ~[classes/:?]
    at example.SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:18) [classes/:?]
```

Note that the filter class is the same as the one in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55036831/3284624).

Also note that I'm not entirely sure how this would work if used with asynchronous logging. There might be some problems using 2 appenders that point to the same file in an async scenario.