# How to migrate PatternLayout extension class from log4j to log4j2

Tags: java, migration, log4j, log4j2

I'm going to migrate an application from log4j to log4j2
I've figured out how to migrate log4j.properties and dependencies

But I have my own class which is extended `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout` but log4j2 bridge library (log4j-1.2-api) has different `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`. Does anybody know how to migrate PatternLayout extension class

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a problem with class `org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser` the class is not existed

Comment: The classes in `log4j-1.2-api` are there to provide binary compatibility for the `org.apache.log4j.Logger` methods. Most of the remaining methods are no-ops, so you need to customize the new `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout` class instead. What does your custom layout do? Does it just add new patterns or something more?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz The thing is that class `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout` cannot be extended because is final

Comment: Additional patterns can be added as plugins. What does your custom layout do?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks a lot. I've already found my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856775/log4j2-programmatic-message-substitution-replacement-for-patternlayout-from-log